# SQL - How do I select only the decimal numbers that only have zero after the semicolon?

Tags: numbers, decimal

i have column Val:
2.32
1234.54
1234.00
1234.5456
1234.54567
and i want only select number like 1234.00
thanks in advance for help

Comment: Hi sir, i opend a new question and if u pls take a look. best regard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select * from mytable where (Round(val,0) - val) = 0

or if you want to 2 decimal places I think this will work

Select * from mytable where (Val - Round(val,2) < .001)

Comment: first, grate thanks for  quick responce, second, the first solution which was what i need. third, i have a very complicated question for me. can i ask u here or i must open another question? and generally thanks alot for ur help

Comment: A new subject should require a new question.

Comment: i got this massage: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.